# Adding tabindex to css :after content

Tags: css, accessibility, pseudo-element

Is there a way I can add tabindex to css generated content added via the :after

```
.main-content:after{
  content: '+';
 ....    
}
```

Essentially a toggle that I need to make accessible (via keyboard)

Comment: If you need to make a toggle accessible via keyboard, you'll probably need an input (such as a button).

Comment: Also, take a look at [CSS Counters.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeking is not currently possible with CSS.

There was a CSS property:

```
nav-index: [number];
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_nav-index.asp unfortunately it is not compatible with any browser right now :(

I know this is not really a solution, but this is the best I could do. Hope you find another way to achieve your wanted behaviour!

Comment: I think my only option will be to forget about :after and add an empty span in my mark-up or something. Not ideal but hey, thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are suggesting is definitely a lot more compatible way to do it. As web devs we have to sacrifice some features/convenience for compatibility after all aye